# How to transfer my Minecraft Pocket Edition world from Android to iOS?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm using an Android smartphone that I purchased Minecraft PE on; now I want to transfer my world to a iPhone. I have also purchased Minecraft PE on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot import a world that requires cross-platform, 
However, you can try to export a map of your world on your Android using a File Manager but it will require your iPhone to be jailbroken which isn't recommended and is very buggy, 
I suggest you put in a suggestion to the Minecraft Pocket Edition team suggesting for the availbitly of exporting maps button included in the next update,

Hope I helped.